# About finally block

Tags: java, try-catch-finally, finally, try-finally

I know `finally`'s purpose is to **guarantee** that some instructions or cleanup code get executed. But what is the actuall difference of using `finally` or putting the code after the catch block.
I mean, give me an example of a case where you need to use `finally` because otherwise the code might not execute at all.

Comment: A `finally` block executes even if you throw and not catch, or catch and rethrow, or `return`. `try{ throw new Error(); } finally { "do somehting"}` still runs the finally.

Comment: could i get code example of each of those scenarios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally will execute regardles of what happends in the catch block. Several cases exist.

```
catch(Exception E)
{
    ...
    throw new OtherException(BetterMessage, E);
}
```

or

```
catch { return null; }
```

or

```
catch { SomeMethodThatWillThrowAnException(); }
```

Thus, even if you return or throw an exception to exit the Catch block, you'll still execute a finally block, while any code simply after the try-catch will be ignored.

Comment: There's the `try { return; } ...` case too, as @Petros P suggested, and the `exit()` case.

Answer (score 1):

finally executes no matter what.

**One example**

```
public void test() {
    try { 
       int x = 0;
       return;
    } catch(Exception ex) { 
       ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally { 
      System.out.println("Hello from finally");
    }  

    System.out.println("Hello from after catch");
}
```

In this case "Hello from after catch" will not be printed but "Hello from finally" will.

Answer (score 0):

A finally block is going to fire no matter what, even if you throw and catch.  Code placed after the catch that's not in a finally block might not execute, for example if your catch might cause a process to end or an application to crash.

Comment: I see. If the application crashes,  what kind of code would I be wanting to run? This is actually what i'm most interested in

Comment: Make sure something gets logged somewhere about the crash.  Try to alert another process about the failure.  Save whatever user data you still can.  Attempt to re-launch the application.  Whatever you want to - this is more of an architecture decision; the FINALLY block is absolutely not *always* necessary, as there will certainly be times where it would have no use in context.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block is executed regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown.

Your question is, *what is the difference of using `finally`, and putting code after the `catch` block*. If an exception is thrown, code after the `catch` block won't be executed. If you place the code in the `finally` block, it will.

Answer (score 0):

There might occur some exception that you won't catch. `finally` block guarantees execution of code inside of it even if unexpected exception is thrown.